# Is there a hotel search tool that allows me to see prices for potential dates?

Tags: online-resources, hotels, accommodation-search-engines

I don't know if this is considered common knowledge, but personally I have found that for a typical week-long trip, the price of the hotel is greater than the price of the flight.

My trip planning, however, relies on choosing travel dates based on optimal flights, and then the traveler begins shopping for hotel rooms.

I would like to plan my holiday the other way around: shop a very particular hotel I would like to return to, and choose a week-long trip there based on the lowest hotel demand, or cheapest price. BUT: I have been unable to find anything like this.

Does such a website exist? (Search for a hotel, with no dates specified, and browse cheap/expensive times to visit that hotel)